# SwiftUI updates reduce FPS of metal window

Tags: swift, swiftui, metal

I'm experimenting with SwiftUI and Metal.  I've got 2 windows, one with various lists and controls and the other a Metal window.

[image: Windows]

I had the slider data updating the Metal window but when I moved the slider the FPS dropped from 60 to around 25.  I removed all links between the views and moving the sliders still drops the FPS in the metal window.

It seems that the list views slow down the FPS as well.

I create the metal window on startup using:

```
    metalWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
                           styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
                           backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    metalWindow.center()
    metalWindow.setFrameAutosaveName("Metal Window")
    metalWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

    mtkView = MTKView()
    mtkView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    metalWindow.contentView!.addSubview(mtkView)
    metalWindow.contentView!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[mtkView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["mtkView" : mtkView!]))
    metalWindow.contentView!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[mtkView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["mtkView" : mtkView!]))

    device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
    mtkView.device = device

    mtkView.colorPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm

    commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!

    mtkView.delegate    = self
    mtkView.sampleCount = 4
    mtkView.clearColor  = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    mtkView.depthStencilPixelFormat = .depth32Float
```

The control window is a SwiftUI view:

```
struct ControlPanelView: View {

    @ObservedObject var controlPanel = ControlPanel()

    @State private var cameraPos   = Floatx3()
    @State private var lightingPos = Floatx3()

    var body: some View {

        HStack{
            VStack{
                VStack{
                    Text("Objects")
                    List(self.controlPanel.objectFiles) { object in
                        Text(object.name)
                    }
                }
                VStack{
                    Text("Textures")
                    List(self.controlPanel.textureFiles) { texture in
                        HStack {
                            Image(nsImage: texture.image).resizable()
                                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                            Text(texture.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            VStack{
                HStack{
                   XYZControl(heading: "Camera Controls",   xyzPos: $cameraPos)
                   XYZControl(heading: "Lighting Controls", xyzPos: $lightingPos)
                }.padding()
                HStack{
                    Text("Frames Per Second:")
                    //Text(String(renderer.finalFpsCount))
                }
            }
        }.border(Color.red).padding()
    }
}

struct XYZControl: View {

    var heading : String
    @Binding var xyzPos : Floatx3

    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            Text(heading).padding(.bottom, 5.0)
            PositionSlider(sliderValue: $xyzPos.x, label: "X", minimum: -15.0, maximum: 15.0)
            PositionSlider(sliderValue: $xyzPos.y, label: "Y", minimum: -15.0, maximum: 15.0)
            PositionSlider(sliderValue: $xyzPos.z, label: "Z", minimum: -15.0, maximum: 15.0)
        }.border(Color.yellow).padding(.leading)
    }
}

struct PositionSlider: View {

    @Binding var sliderValue : Float
    var label   : String
    var minimum : Float
    var maximum : Float

    static let posFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(label)
            HStack{
                Text("\(Self.posFormatter.string(from:NSNumber(value: minimum))!)")
                Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: minimum ... maximum)
                Text("\(Self.posFormatter.string(from:NSNumber(value: maximum))!)")
            }.padding(.horizontal).frame(width: 150.0, height: 15.0, alignment: .leading)
            Text("\(Self.posFormatter.string(from:NSNumber(value: sliderValue))!)")
        }.border(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with why the frame rate drops?

I removed the metal window and incorporated it into the control window using NSViewRepresentable so it looks like this now:
[image: All in one window]

This still has the same problem.

The render code (not doing much!). It still slows down even when not rendering the teapot.

```
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {

        if let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() {

            commandBuffer.label = "Frame command buffer"

            if let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: view.currentRenderPassDescriptor!) {

                renderEncoder.label = "render encoder"

                renderEncoder.endEncoding()
            }

            commandBuffer.present(view.currentDrawable!)

            commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { completedCommandBuffer in
                self.computeFPS()
            }
            commandBuffer.commit()
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you measure FPS?

Comment: I just use a simple timer called from a commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler.  The spinning teapot in the metal view also slows downs when the sliders are moved.

Comment: Can you show the render code?

Comment: I've added the render code.  I removed the rendering of the scene so it's not doing much and the fps still drops.

Comment: I think your SwiftUI is blocking the main thread.

Comment: I think so too, how would I get round this?  I’m not really that familiar with threads in swift.

Comment: As 0xBFE1A8 said SwiftUI was blocking the main thread.  I moved the draw function into a callback setup using CVDisplayLink .global(qos: .userInteractive).  This stops the rendering slowing down when the sliders are moved.

Comment: it is excellent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As 0xBFE1A8 said SwiftUI was blocking the main thread.  I moved the draw function into a callback setup using CVDisplayLink .global(qos: .userInteractive).  This stops the rendering slowing down when the sliders are moved.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble with SwiftUI and MTKView but I can't find how to get the callback setup to work. Could you edit the answer adding some code or pseudocode? I'd like to have the option to render on a background thread with fixed fps via CVDisplayLink callback and also to render on demand based on events (`mtkView.isPaused = true` and calling draw). I don't know how to setup the link in swift. And when I call draw from background reacting to an event (with `.global(qos: .userInteractive`) it still executes in main. I might be missing something or don't understand how the pieces fit.

Comment: @Affinity It's been a while since I last looked at this, give me a couple of days and I'll see what I can find.